# ErrorCode "12200" XML Validation warning: " Cannot find the declaration of element 'html'."

Tags: twilio

I am trying to run the code sample given by Twilio devs: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/ivr-phone-tree-csharp

When I call my test number, the code doesn't execute because of the warning 
"XML Validation warning"
line    "1"
parserMessage   " Cannot find the declaration of element 'html'."
ErrorCode   "12200"
LogLevel    "WARN"

and the XML that allegedly has the problem is Twilio's own code that has the "html" tags just fine.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
        <title>IVR Phone Tree</title>
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-k2/8zcNbxVIh5mnQ52A0r3a6jAgMGxFJFE2707UxGCk= sha512-ZV9KawG2Legkwp3nAlxLIVFudTauWuBpC10uEafMHYL0Sarrz5A7G79kXh5+5+woxQ5HM559XX2UZjMJ36Wplg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body-content"></div>
        <footer>
        Made with 
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> by your pals

            <a href="http://www.twilio.com">@twilio</a>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what the problem really is? I have already had to add closing tags, comment out DOCTYPE.. I am getting frustrated to find that the sample that is supposed to teach me something doesn't actually work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When Twilio makes a webhook request to your application to find out what to do with the incoming call, it expects the response to be XML, [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) in fact. Instead, your application is serving HTML, which Twilio doesn't know what to do with.

I would ensure that your phone number is configured to point to the correct path in the application, which should be `http://<your-ngrok-subdomain>.ngrok.io/ivr/welcome`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: thank you, that was it. I had followed some other instructions and my path was  http://<your-ngrok-subdomain>.ngrok.io 
As soon as I corrected it, the application started working.

Comment: Fantastic! Would you mind marking the answer as correct so that others can see it helped? Thanks!